# property assign

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

If I have one property like this, what is the diference of assign the value of the property of the first mode and the second mode?

```
@interface Prueba : NSObject{
    CustomeClass *_cclass;
}
@property(nonatomic, retain)CustomeClass *cclass;

@end

@implementation Prueba

@synthesize cclass = _cclass

- (void)config{
    // 1 This
    self.cclass = [[CustomeClass alloc] init];

    // 2 This or
    CustomeClass *cc = [[CustomeClass alloc] init];
    self.cclass = cc;
    [cc release];
}

@end
```

:/

Comment: Did you mean the `[cc release]` line to be part of the second mode, or common to both?

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference in the result except that in the second method you create an additional pointer. In both versions `self.cclass` will hold your object just fine.

The problem is that when you only release the object in your second mode, in the first mode you'll have a memory leak. Since the `retainCount` of an object is +1 when you allocate it, you assign a +1 object through your setter. This means, that you actually bump up the `retainCount` again. Now if you don't release the object after assigning it to your property, once it gets released from there the `retainCount` will only be reduced by 1. Thus letting an object with a `retainCount` of +1 float around in the memory, lost forever.

But because you are already asking about a better version, I want to introduce lazy instantiation to you. What you can do, is that you overwrite the getter method of the property in question and check if it has been allocated yet. If not, you allocate it inside your getter method and then return it. It would look something like this:

```
- (CustomeClass*) cclass
{
  if(!_cclass)
  {
    _cclass = [[CustomeClass alloc] init];
  }
  return _cclass;
}
```

With this method you assign a +1 retained object to an internal variable, thus bypassing the setter and not increasing the `retainCount`. Also it's memory friendly, because you object only gets instantiated when you really need it. Now when you set your property to nil or some new object, the old object will be properly deallocated.

EDIT:

In response to Robert Ryan's comment I want to add the following:

This does not break KVO, or interfere with the assigned qualifies for your properties. If your property is marked as `assign` or `weak`, then lazy instantiation doesn't really make sense. If it's marked as `retain` or `strong` this way of instantiating an object is perfectly fine, especially when it is a property which you would assign anyway inside a config method.

Regarding KVO: the value which is assigned inside the getter can be seen as the initial/default value, so KVO still works. It will trigger when you use the setter to assign something else to the property. You wouldn't want KVO to trigger because of a default value, would you?

Comment: Except for the -retainCount business.  The actual retainCount of that thing would be UInt_Max.

Comment: Why would that be UInt_Max and not just +1? I'm curious.

Comment: Because the method -retainCount is the most f-Ed up part of Objective-C, that's why.

Comment: Haha, yeah well I learned never to rely on that at all in my code - and well, ARC is here.

Comment: ARC didn't fix -retainCount.  Try it with an NSString right now.

Comment: At least it doesn't let you use it anymore in code, so you won't rely on it to be accurate. (Can't try right now, not on my mac)

Comment: I don't like the suggestion of bypassing the setter. You lose the benefit of the attributes of your property (where it retains if it needs, it doesn't if it's an assign). You also break KVO logic when you bypass the setter.

Comment: Actually lazy instantiation is something that's been suggested by Paul Hegarty. It only applies if there is no object set the first time you use the getter, thus making sure that you don't end up with a nil value. I never said you should avoid the setter in general. You should _always_ use the setter in any other situation. But what he does is just setting up something inside a config method, which can be done cleaner using lazy instantiation.

Comment: Also, you say that his second example will cause a leak. Don't you mean his first example will cause the leak?

Comment: Also, if you're going to set the private var directly, don't you want to do the appropriate `willChangeValueForKey` and `didChangeValueForKey`, too?

Comment: Nope, I said "_The problem is that when you only release the object in your second mode, you'll have a memory leak._", which is referring to the first method not having a release. Read the updated answer regaring you KVO-concerns.

Answer (score 0):

Your first example gives you an object with a retain count of two (wrong), whereas your second example gives you an object with retain count of one (right). The second method is preferred in non-ARC projects. Alternatively, you could also do either set the ivar yourself (which I don't like because you're not using the setter):

```
_cclass = [[CustomeClass alloc] init];
```

or use the setter as your examples do, but do an autorelease (which I don't like because you shouldn't defer your releases unless you have to):

```
self.cclass = [[[CustomeClass alloc] init] autorelease];
```

In your non-ARC project, your original second example is best (using a pointer, using your property's setter, then releasing your pointer), because for KVO you want to get in the habit of using the setter:

```
CustomeClass *cc = [[CustomeClass alloc] init];
self.cclass = cc;
[cc release];
```

Comment: Actually the statement that "the latter is preferred" is wrong. It would actually be better to allocate, assign and then release, thus immediatly freeing the non needed memory, instead of having it floating around until it gets scraped because of the autorelease. If it's possible to avoid autorelease, do it.

Comment: That's precisely what I meant, @NTTake's latter example, not my autorelease example. I've clarified accordingly. Academically, it doesn't matter because nothing is getting released anyway (the autorelease is just deferring the reduction of the retainCount, but the property is retained, so no memory is getting freed), but I always subscribe to releasing immediately whenever I can and only using autorelease when I want to return an object to a caller and let them take ownership if they so choose.